# Fitting a curve without knowing function type in python

Tags: python, interpolation, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a smooth curve to a set of data that's very noisy. By using the "UnivariateSpline" function from scipy I have almost managed to reach my goal, but the fitting of the curve seems to not be able to fit the beginning correctly.
The first picture shows the whole plot (red is the fitted curve, green the noisy data).

*First plot*
[image: First plot]

The second picture is zoomed in on the part that the fitting gets wrong.

*Second plot with the fitting error*
[image: Second plot with the fitting error]

Does anyone have an idea for how to make this more aligned with the green data?

I have tried splitting up the first part of the data (from x=0 to the spike,  an exponential-like curve) and the second part from the top of the spike and out (a negative exponential function).  But this didn't work.

In the end, the important thing is to always have increasing values of y with increasing x before the spike, and the opposite with increasing x after the spike.

Comment: Is the data that you need to fit always in a different shape? Because the plot that you show almost screams for a piecewise function of two exponentials! One covering the first flat bit up until your peak and another one that takes over at that point for the exponential decay. Alternatively, you could look at distributions such as inverse Weibull which should reasonably well approximate your data as well!

Comment: It will always look like this yes. I thought about splitting it up into before and after the peak, but I'm not very used to fitting functions, so I don't know how to fit an exponential function to the first and then a negative exponential to the second. Do you have any good way of doing this? scipy.curve_fit?

Comment: Easiest is if you just split your data into two chunks split at the maximum and just do separate fits. Depending on how noisy your data is, you might need to put a bit of work into identifying the maximum. Afterwards you can then simply use `scipy.curve_fit` as shown in the documentation. Theoretically, you could also use something like `np.heaviside`, but seems a bit unnecessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

First, if the data is noisy and you don't care to fit the noise, then interpolation is always tricky because of its focus on fitting all the data points. It may be ok for a one-off analysis though.

The issue that you're observing is the trade-off set by the smoothing factor and the sharp transition in your data. You can try to reduce `s` to a value smaller than the number of data points, but you may find that it will start to  fit the noise.

Otherwise, I'd recommend that you try fitting an [MLP model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html). Be sure to use `activation='tanh'` as that will make the function approximation smoother. You may also want to increase `alpha`, which controls the weight decay and further helps to keep the neural net function smooth. Lastly, set `early_stopping=True` to reduce the chances of overfitting to the noise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try adjusting the 's' value. If that doesn't help, I will look into the MLP model!